# the numeral content that I want to add to the txt file and is encrypted. C

Tags: c

summarizing what I'm doing, I'm carrying out a supermarket management project. in which I have to make a list saved in a txt file for the clients and products, and I'm confused because it worked on the clients, but on the products it is encrypted.

I imagine that the problem is in the code that I am going to put here.
this is the structure of the products

```
typedef struct _produto{
    int ID;
    char nome[10];
    float preco;
    int validade;
    int quantidade;
    struct _produto* next;
} Produto;
```

this is a procedure that will ask the values to user

```
void adicionarP(Produto* listaProduto) {
    Produto* novoProduto = (Produto*)calloc(1, sizeof(Produto));
    int auxInt = -1;
    float auxF = -1;
    
    printf("Digite o nome do produto: ");
    fflush(stdin); 
    fgets(novoProduto->nome, 10, stdin);
    novoProduto->nome[strcspn(novoProduto->nome, "\n")] = 0; // tira a nova linha "\n" que tenho no nome
    
    novoProduto->ID= obterIdAleatorioP(listaProduto);
    
    printf("Digite o preco do produto:");
    scanf("%f", &auxF);
    fflush(stdin);
    novoProduto->preco = auxF;

    auxInt = -1;
    printf("Digite a validade do produto:");
    scanf("%d", &auxInt);
    fflush(stdin);
    novoProduto->validade = auxInt;
    
    auxInt = -1;
    printf("Digite a Quantidade do stock:");
    scanf("%d", &auxInt);
    fflush(stdin);
    novoProduto->quantidade = auxInt;
    
    listaProduto = adicionarProduto(listaProduto, novoProduto);

    printf("\nAdicionado com sucesso!\n");
}
```

in the procedure above there are two functions, one called "adicionarProduto" that will basically see the list and when null will add the new product

```
Produto* adicionarProduto(Produto *listaProduto, Produto *novoProduto)
{
    if(listaProduto == NULL) return novoProduto;

    listaProduto->next = adicionarProduto(listaProduto->next, novoProduto);

    return listaProduto;
}
```

the function obterIdAleatorioP will generate a random id

```
int obterIdAleatorioP(Produto* listaProdutos) {
    int randomId;
    time_t t;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    
    do {
        randomId = rand() % 10; 
    } while(existeProduto(listaProdutos,randomId));
    
    return randomId;
}
```

before doing any function(example: the function in the top) txt file:

```
1:IceCream:2.00:123:321
```

after doin any function txt file:

```
11802128:IceCream:2.00:123:321:0.000000:11802152:11802148
11825056::0.000000:11825080:11825076
11802176:pe:0.000000:11802200:11802196
```

Comment: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714)

Comment: [about `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Comment: I tried to remove this function and add as I add the other numbers and it didn't come encrypted again. but thanks for your time, I appreciate it very much

Comment: What do you mean by "on the products it's encrypted"?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text.

Comment: i update the post, now there are example of txt file maybe it will be easier to understand

Comment: @FranciscoLemos Images of code / output cause multiple problems compared to formatted code as text, see meta post [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251)

Comment: @FranciscoLemos maybe, but still post you text as properly formatted text.

Comment: By "encrypted", do you mean that the data is not understood? or do you mean that it is actually encrypted and you can decrypt it to reproduce the original data?  I suspect your data is not actually encrypted.

Comment: I imagine it's being encrypted but that's what I think I don't know if it's not being recognized or not. is that I think I have the data collection right, but yes, that could be the problem. but as you can see only the numbers are like this the name is right